# delphi oracle blob

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-7

how to insert blob data into oracle xe from delphi 7 (ado component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check these samples using a [`TAdoQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOQuery) component.

loading the data directly from a file

```
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='Param1';
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').LoadFromFile('yourfilename',ftBlob);
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO TableName (FieldName) VALUES (:Param1)');
 ADoQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

using a Stream to load the data

```
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.AddParameter.Name:='Param1';
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').LoadFromStream(AStream,ftBlob);
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO TableName (FieldName) VALUES (:Param1)');
 ADoQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

you must be aware which the [`Microsoft Oracle oledb driver`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661) is not compatible with `blob fields` try instead using the [`Oracle OLEDB provider`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28431/using.htm).

As final advice if you can, try using another components to connect to ORACLE like dbexpress, [`ANYDAC`](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) or the [`ODAC`](http://www.devart.com/odac/) components

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Oracle has a peculiar way to handle LOBs. It uses "LOB locators" (a sort of handles) to perform operations on LOBs. An INSERT returns a LOB locator that is then used to fill the LOB, for example. That operation could be performed "behind the scenes" by the driver/library used to access Oracle, or may require some coding.